# How does 'IN' works in db2 sql query?

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe

My requirement is to select data from DB2 table where phone number is equal to 16 set of phone numbers.I have tried to run this query given below on my local test data and my program is successfully working!
But , when i try to run this same program on real table(backup table) , my RUN jcl is getting failed with S722 abend.

i feel it is not space abend because we are using file with attributes of 7 cylinders(1 primary,6 secondary). According to my research i found out that sql query with 'IN ,'LIKE' takes too much time to execute so changed Time parameter in Jobcard to NOLIMIT. But noluck !!

Can someone help me with any other way of writing this query ? or help me to rectify this issue....

query like this :

```
EXEC SQL
DECLARE WS-CURSOR CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
SELECT CUST_ID,CUST_NAME,SEQ_NUM,PHONE_NUM FROM PHONE_TAB 
  WHERE PHONE_NUM IN ('123456789','789456123','456789123','789456123' etc) AND
        PHONE_TYPE = 'DU' 
END-EXEC.
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What does your `FETCH` look like? The reason I ask is that the failure isn't on the declare, that is not executable, and S722 could be an array size issue.

Comment: What is the definition of the columns PHONE_NUM and PHONE_TYPE?

Comment: Use JOBPARM LINES=999999. This should let you write all the lines in the output. By the way, how many output records are you expecting? And I believe Phone_type should be in quotes as 'DU'.

Comment: @cschneid you should write an answer, the other answers below are incorrect

Comment: @SaggingRufus I've incorporated my comment (now deleted) into an answer.  Hopefully this will be helpful to the OP and others in the future.  Thanks for the prompt, sometimes I waffle between commenting and answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sx22 family of abends indicate exceeding some system defined parameter.  A S322 typically indicates you've exceeded the amount of CPU time in the TIME parameter on your job card or job step, for example.

A S722 abend indicates you have produced more spool output than is allowed by your shop's JES parameters. You need to determine the source of that spool output to resolve the abend.

You may have a core dump (CEEDUMP), debugging output you've coded (SYSOUT or SYSPRINT or STDOUT or STDERR), or a runaway report DD you've coded.  The JESMSGLG DD visible in the spool either at the top of your output in SDSF or by selecting your job with a '?' may report errors *prior* to the S722.

Perhaps you are experiencing a S322 which *leads to* the S722.  This is entirely possible since the problem occurs with a large quantity of data.

Setting the time parameter to NOLIMIT is an expensive debugging technique as most mainframe shops have a chargeback algorithm in place, typically CPU time = money in someone's budget.  Your shop may have a JES exit in place that substitutes some other value for NOLIMIT specifically to prevent its use.

As indicated by user6542823, you could add a JOBPARM LINES=some-large-number to get around the S722, but you'll still have to resolve the underlying problem.

z/OS tries to give you as much information as possible to debug.  Make use of what it gives you.

Given...

- you've said your program executes fine with local test data
- the problem manifests when running against a backup of the production sized data

...then *if*...

- the definition of table PHONE_TAB in your local test data matches that in the backup and the production data
- your program binds successfully
- you have authorization to read the backup data

...the problem is likely not with your SQL but rather related to the volume of data.

Look at the EXPLAIN output for your package and you'll likely see you're scanning the entire PHONE_TAB table.  Perhaps there is an index in place in production that is absent in the backup you're testing against.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a inline table join instead of doing a where in clause

IRL I would put the values into a temp table and join to the temp table.   But for example I've done this in-line.

```
SELECT CUST_ID,CUST_NAME,SEQ_NUM,PHONE_NUM FROM PHONE_TAB

join (
values('123456789'),('789456123'),('456789123'),('789456123')
) as b (ph) on phone_num = ph

where PHONE_TYPE = DU
```

Two table query might be fastest hard to tell but for me it is definitely easier to maintain two tables than a program that creates a SQL statement every time it runs.

```
SELECT CUST_ID,CUST_NAME,SEQ_NUM,PHONE_NUM FROM PHONE_TAB

join look_tab b on phone_num = b.ph

where PHONE_TYPE = DU
```

Comment: ....is there an appreciable performance difference for doing this?  I would have (naively) assumed that the optimizer is going to turn them all into an in-memory lookup of some sort, that the plan should be identical.

Comment: IRL In Real Lifle I would have two tables one the phone_tab and one  look_tab.  Look_tab is populated with just the phone# I'm looking for then I would run the query and check the indexer recommendations.  With two tables you'd know you always have an optimized query and don't have to deal with the minutia of creating a text statement everytime you run the query.  I definitely would be faster with two tables because you'd be using  the recommended indexes and such.

Comment: ....except that probably doesn't apply if you're using a small temp table.  An index represents a tradeoff of space for (less) time, and crucially, still has a cost.  Optimizers ignore indices they don't think provide sufficient benefit.  If your table (or temporary result set) is small enough, the optimizer is going to slurp it up into an in-memory working set and ignore whatever indices you've declared (although they may be useful for certain statistics).  This also ignores the cost of multiple trips to the database (for the insertion), and maintaining the index.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  I believe there would be an existing index over phone number.   This is the time of year to Believe.

Comment: Oh, I don't doubt that an index on `PHONE_TAB` is (or should be) present, and that it will be used.  What I'm much less sure of is that an index on a **lookup** table is going to be used.